# Error installing libsystemd-dev

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to install libsystemd-dev on my fully updated 18.04LTS server.  I get this error message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsystemd-dev : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 237-3ubuntu10.53) but 237-3ubuntu10.54 is to be installed

What is the workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: The expected package for *bionic* (18.04) is `libsystemd0 | 237-3ubuntu10.53  | bionic-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` so your issue is you've added some packages from *-proposed* (or some other source, ie. `libsystemd0 | 237-3ubuntu10.54  | bionic-proposed | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` but not all.  You shouldn't use `-proposed` unless you have a specific reason.

Comment: I don't see where we've enabled "proposed".  However, is there a graceful way to recover?  Is there an option to remove 10.54 and install 10.53?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with `apt-cache policy libsystemd0` as someone with `sudo` rights has added it on your system, either from *direct* install (`wget` & `dpkg -i`) or via some source added to your system... Also start by looking at your sources (`sudo apt update`) and look for missing lines, and any extra lines that don't belong there, or look at your sources directly...   *I'd suggest this, as if you don't know how it got there, you may have other polluted packages installed on your system so use this chance to explore first whilst the problem is easily seen*)